# Mock a Call Activity subprocess in activiti

Tags: jbpm, activiti

I'm writing a set of unit tests for activiti (1.13) workflows. We're using a Call Activity subprocess for a set of actions that are re-used between different workflows, but I'd really like to be able to mock out the whole subprocess without needing to actually step through the individual workflow tasks of the subprocess.

Is this possible? I haven't found any documentation for it (yet!) but that doesn't mean that the function isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the method CallActivity#setProcessDefinitonKey to redefine at runtime which process will be called.

The idea is to replace the name of the called process at runtime.
Then you can provide a 'dumb' process that just do nothing, or you can define some more elaborated process that does something (like returning a values, or call some java code)

The pseudo code algo is like this:

```
redefine(process, target, replacement) {
  ProcessDefinitionEntity processDefinition = getProcessDefinition(process)
  foreach ActivityImpl activity in processDefinition.getActivities() {
    if(activity instanceceof CallActivityBehavior and activity.name == target) {
      activity.setProcessDefinitonKey(replacement)    
    }
  }  
}
```

You need to define the getProcessDefinition method too:

```
ProcessDefinitionImpl processDefinition = Context
      .getProcessEngineConfiguration()
      .getDeploymentManager()
      .findDeployedLatestProcessDefinitionByKey(inProcess);

    return processDefinition.getProcessDefinition()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spy (`Mockito.spy()`)  `org.drools.KnowledgeBase` within `org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession` and mock method `org.drools.KnowledgeBase#getProcess()`

It will look something like that:

```
KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = createKnowledgeBase();
kbase = spy(knowledgeBase);
ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
Whitebox.setInternalState(ksession,"kbase",kbase);
doReturn(kbase.getProcess("processToMockWith")).when(kbase).getProcess(eq("processToMock"));
```

Answer (score -1):

In your deployment statement substitute a simplified "mock" model

@Deployment(resources = {"PathToModelUnderTest", "PathToSimplifiedCallActivityModel"})

As long as the simplified CallActivity model has the name the CallActivity expects you'll be fine